# Is this display broken or is it a bug?

Tags: display, intel-fpga

After being fine for several days and picked up after transport, I found that one part of the Altera DE2 display is not working, you see where it is a 9 there should be an 8 so it is just like that part should be lit be isn't and that part of the display always fails to light:

[image]

So it fails the test, should I try and contact Altera for a warranty or something since the board is brand new? Any ideas? I think everything seems that the fourth unit from the right is broken in the southwest position. Do you agree?

There are ways to programmaticly light that part of the display as described in the manual but I didn't try, is that any idea if it fails the test? It is broken isn't it?

### Update

after some more tests and contact with the supplier's support and sales, the supplier has decided to send me new parts i.e.

```
Part No.    Description Quantity    Reference
MDL-3015-ELG    7-Segment (Common Anode), RoHS  5
```

Do you think this will work to replace the faulty part? How do I replace the part once I've gotten it from the supplier?

### Update 2013-07-29

I took it to a computer shop and they could solder on a new segment and now it's working. I'm real glad. Now I got two FPGA and I'm going to contact Altera if they want the DE2-115 back since all my development is for the DE2.

Comment: "Southwest position" is also called [segment E](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/02/7_segment_display_labeled.svg/220px-7_segment_display_labeled.svg.png).

Comment: Maybe there was a bad solder joint and it was...knocked off in transport? Probably not, but still - check the solder joints.

Comment: I would first reflow all the solder joints on that part, since that's quick and easy.  If that doesn't work, make it Altera's problem.  They should replace it since it failed so quickly.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Thanks for looking at it. It appeared to be a whole faulty line since my instructors also got faulty board. Altera replaced me with a DE-115 and let me keep the DE2.

Comment: @Nick: That implies they might well be aware of a production problem with a lot of the DE2 boards.  Seems like they did the right thing.

Comment: @OlinLathrop It was possible to solder on a new segment and now the DE2 is like new again. I might have fed it too much current(?) but anyhow now it feels like I owe Altera money since I've got both the DE2 and the DE2-115 and I only paid for a DE2. I'm going to contact Altera and tell them how I feel that they have given me more than I should have gotten. They could have told me just take it to a workshop (since I shouldn't debut my own soldering on a fine nice FPGA).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Ask Altera for an RMA and get it repaired, failing that, ask them to send out a replacement part, otherwise.
2. You need to know the exact P/N to determine if it is Common Anode or Common Cathode, filtered lens and same pin pattern.  None of this is possible from your photo.